# How to Configure Commons VFS to call GETmethod of http

Tags: java, http, http-get, apache-commons-vfs

I am calling one API which supports get call to download a file. But when I call resolveFile metthod of FileSystemManager it calls HEAD method by default. Can anybody tell me how to call a HTTP GET in Commons VFS ? Some way to set request method like we have it in HttpURLConnection?

```html
FileObject fileObject = VFS.getManager().resolveFile("http://somedownloadurl");// This calls HTTP HEAD. How to make it call HTTP GET
```